# Exchanging publicKeys of RSA encryption method in an android chat application

Tags: android, rsa, chat, public-key-encryption, wifi-direct

I want to use RSA in a android chat application which works through WIFI-Direct.
I should exchange public keys between server phone and client phone at the beginning of chat session. how should I do that?
any framework or Library is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WiFi direct, but if you use TCP with it then you should use SSL/TLS. If you don't make connections using a domain name then you will have to be creative to properly authenticate the end points.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you pease tell me how to do this with SSL/TLS? cause I dont use a domain name. two phones connect with each other through wifi direct. I think something should be there for wifi-direct like that.